# Question about volume of water

Tags: homework-and-exercises, geometry, volume

As shown in the figure, the lead straight cross-section of a reservoir and two mountains is shown. The rectangular groove at the bottom represents the reservoir, and the isosceles triangle on both sides represents the mountain. In order to estimate the impact of heavy rain in mountainous areas on the reservoir water level, assuming that when extending vertically to paper, the direct lead cross-section of the reservoir and the two mountains remains unchanged, so the slopes on both sides of the reservoir can be regarded as flat slopes with an oblique angle of 45°. If the total rainfall in mountainous areas and reservoirs is 400 mm, the mountain height H is 500 meters, the width of the reservoir is 100 meters, and all the rainwater on both sides of the declining water flow into and accumulates in the reservoir, how many meters will the water level of the reservoir increase?
[image]

*my problem when solving it is that it doesn’t provide the length of the bottom.thanks a lot*

Comment: It says *the width of the reservoir is 100 meters*

Comment: Sorry,I meant the length of the bottom is unknown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is straightforward if you understand the units. The rainfall rate is usually given in $\text{mm}$, but this actually means *water height in millimeters in a square meter per hour*, or *liters per hour in a square meter*.

> The total rainfall in mountainous areas and reservoirs is 400 mm

It is unclear what you mean by *total*, i.e. the time component is unknown. It is not necessary to know the time component in order to solve this problem, but you should have in mind that the final height difference you calculate is related to this (unknown) time!

Length of one side of a mountain is $L = H/\sin\theta$. Now just calculate the total volume *captured* by the two sides of the mountain and the reservoir, and then divide this by the reservoir width to get the height difference in the reservoir.

> My problem when solving it is that it doesn’t provide the length of the bottom

It is not possible to solve this without knowing the width of the reservoir. Let me simplify - if you pour 10 L of water in a tank, what will be increase in the water level? Answer to this question depends on the tank area, or in your case the reservoir length.